# JavaScript convert string hrefs into onClicks

Tags: javascript, regex, onclick, href

I've got strings with multiple standard links like

```
<a href="http://example.com">Name of Link</a>
```

and I'm trying to turn them into

```
<a onClick="myFunc('http://example.com','Name of Link')">Name of Link</a>
```

or even just:

```
<a onClick="myFunc('http://example.com')">Name of Link</a>
```

would be great if the former was unnecessarily difficult. The links are being dynamically inserted into the DOM so event handlers won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need event handlers that prevents the default action and get the `href`

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=anchors.length; i--;) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click', func, false);
}

function func(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = this.getAttribute('href'),
        text = this.innerText;
    myFunc(href, text);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fy77p79b/1/)

If you have to work with strings, you can do something like this

```js
var str = '<a href="http://example1.com">Name of Link 1</a><br /><a href="http://example2.com">Name of Link 2</a><br /><a href="http://example3.com">Name of Link 3</a><br /><a href="http://example4.com">Name of Link 4</a>';

var parser  = new DOMParser();
var doc     = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");
var anchors = doc.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=anchors.length; i--;) {
    var href = anchors[i].getAttribute('href'),
        text = anchors[i].innerText;
        
    anchors[i].setAttribute('onclick', "myFunc('"+href+"', '"+text+"')");
    anchors[i].removeAttribute('href');
}

str = doc.body.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = str;

function myFunc(href, text) {
  alert(href + ' - ' + text);
}
```

Comment: And what do you mean by `dynamically posting`, are they inserted into the DOM at a later time?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to change the links before inserting it into the DOM

Comment: Then parse the HTML, [don't work with string replacements in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454)

Comment: If you have the control over string then why don't you create in the way you want it ?

Comment: @Rayon It's being grabbed from a database that I don't have control over :s

Comment: Once you update the DOM using DB data, execute code provided above. There are tricky ways to update the string as a DOM before inserting in DOM too...

Comment: Mm. I was really hoping for the latter since the app I'm creating is getting a bit more complicated so I'd have to find all the instances where things are being dynamically inserted, but nonetheless I'll try it out! thanks!

Comment: @MichaelTruong - updated with something that should work with strings, and parses the HTML

Comment: @adeneo not exactly what I was expecting the answer to look like but it works :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

HTML

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="myFunction(this.href,this.textContent)">
  My link
</a>
```

JS

```
function myFunction(getAttr,text){
console.log(getAttr,text);

}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r17ex6d0/11/)

**EDIT**

if you are looking to prohibit  `href` action then you have to use

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Updated JS

```
function myFunction(event,getAttr,text){
event.preventDefault();
console.log(getAttr,text);
}
```

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r17ex6d0/12/)

Comment: the links start off without the onclick, I'm trying to replace the href with it...

Comment: @MichaelTruong I am sorry I could not get your problem.Did you mean that you dont want href to execute it's action?

Comment: The first line of code is how it starts off, the second line is what I'm trying to turn it into

Comment: So does that mean on initial page load you will have href attribute and then it will be replaced by onclick?

Comment: the page is already loaded, the href is just a string for now that would be inserted into the DOM later

Answer (score 0):

> Append your `string` in a temporary `element` and manipulate it as explained by [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo)

Try this:

```js
var str = '<a href="http://example.com">Name of Link</a>';
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerHTML = str;
var targetEleme = elem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
targetEleme.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = this.getAttribute('href'),
    text = this.innerText;
  myFunc(href, text);
});
document.body.appendChild(targetEleme);

function myFunc(href, text) {
  alert('HREF: ' + href + '   TEXT: ' + text);
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gcj8dana/)

Comment: Hmm, I tried playing with this a bit. I can't tell, if I'm looping through a database would the event listener disappear? and wouldn't this not work for strings with other text and multiple links?